# Automation attempt with Selenium to connect with people on Linkedin

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, linkedin-api

I am currently using Selenium for automation to connect with Recruiters through Linkedin in an automated way. The login works, also my script enters the keywords of "IT Recruiter" but the problem comes when Chrome is in this section, it does not click on the "Connect" button, so it just goes to page number 2 of recruiters, then to number 3, but without clicking on the "Connect" button.

What exactly is going wrong in my code?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException

def login(driver, username, password):
    driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/login?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin")
    user = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))
    user.send_keys(username)
    password_elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "password")))
    password_elem.send_keys(password)
    password_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

def connect_with_recruiters(driver):
    for index in range(1, 101):
        print(f"Procesando página {index}")
        
        base_url = f"https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/?keywords=IT%20recruiter&origin=HISTORY&page={index}"
        driver.get(base_url)
        
        try:
            # Esperar a que la página cargue completamente
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Conectar')]")))
            
            # Hacer clic en todos los botones "Conectar"
            connect_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Conectar')]")
            
            for connect_button in connect_buttons:
                try:
                    # Hacer clic en Conectar usando execute_script
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", connect_button)
                    time.sleep(2)  # Pausa para esperar que aparezca el nuevo popup
                    
                    # Esperar a que aparezca el botón "Conectar sin nota" en el nuevo popup
                    connect_without_note_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Conectar sin nota']")))
                    connect_without_note_button.click()
                    
                    print("Conectado con un reclutador exitosamente.")
                    
                    # Añadir código para la nueva funcionalidad de seguimiento
                    try:
                        # Clic en el botón de seguimiento si está presente
                        follow_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Seguir']")
                        follow_button.click()
                        print("Comenzó a seguir al reclutador.")
                    except NoSuchElementException:
                        # No se encontró el botón de seguimiento, imprimir mensaje
                        print("El botón de seguimiento no está presente.")
                    
                except (TimeoutException, StaleElementReferenceException) as e:
                    # Capturar errores de tiempo de espera o referencia de elemento caducado
                    print(f"Error al conectar con el reclutador: {e}")
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    # Cerrar si se solicita un correo electrónico
                    print("Reclutador requería correo electrónico, cerrado.")
                    close_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Cerrar']")
                    close_button.click()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error inesperado al conectar con el reclutador: {e}")
        except TimeoutException as e:
            print(f"TimeoutException al buscar reclutadores en la página {index}: {e}")
            continue  # Salta a la siguiente iteración del bucle
        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            print(f"No se encontraron elementos de reclutadores en la página {index}: {e}")
            continue  # Salta a la siguiente iteración del bucle
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error general en la página {index}: {e}")
            continue  # Salta a la siguiente iteración del bucle

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    
    your_username = "USERNAME"
    your_password = "PASSWORD"
    
    try:
        login(driver, your_username, your_password)
        connect_with_recruiters(driver)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error general en el script: {e}")
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

I add a image so that you can see exactly what I mean

[image]

Comment: What do you get if you print `connect_buttons`?

Comment: i have tried it and it does not show any print

Comment: Add logging statements to print out what the script is doing and where it might be failing. This can help identify the exact point of failure. (As your code seems right)

Answer (score 0):

The connect button doesn't contain the text "Conectar", the span inside the button have it.

try this way:

```
connect_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Conectar')]")
```

Comment: Nope. It still does not work. The truth is that I'm a bit confused because the code seems to be correct

Comment: Please, try my new solution